# Is there a way to run some code only if generic type was resolved as 'never'?

Tags: typescript

The situation (simplified) which rises this question is the following:
I have a generic class like this:

```
class Request<Parameter,Response>{}
```

Sometimes request have parameters, sometimes they don't, so this generic typically has these two kinds of resolutions:

```
class RequestWithParam extends Request<Parameter1,Response1>{}
class RequestWithoutParam extends Request<never,Response2>{}
```

Requests with parameters are intended to be executed when `Observable<Parameter>` fires, and requests without parameter should be executed as soon as possible.

This is a common idea, so it should be implemented in base Request class.
However my googling couldn't give me a solution for this problem.
Ideally I'd prefer to solve it with function overloading like that (pseudocode since it seems typescript doesn't have what I want it to):

```
class Request<Parameter,Response>{
    constructor<Parameter=never>(){
        this.execute();
    }
    constructor<Parameter=Not<never>>(){
        ///do nothing and wait for parameters
    }
}
```

The following pseudo-solution also would satisfy me (google shows that something like this is possible in c#, but obviously not in typescript). I can't check `typeof` real parameter value at runtime because it would be `undefined` in both cases - in the first one it's never needed, and in the other we are waiting for it, maybe even forever). So I need to check for type definition instead of actual runtime type:

```
 class Request<Parameter,Response>{
      constructor(){
            if(typeof(Parameter)==="never"){
                this.execute();
            }
      }
 }
```

This pseudo-solution also would be fine (surely it knows at compiled type the type of parameterField, so technically it could generate two functions `_initialize_never()` and `_initialize_object(someobj)`, and resolve which one to actually include in code based on the parameter type, however function overloading in typescript is not a true function overloading, it's just 'declaration overloading', so this won't work)

```
 class Request<Parameter,Response>{
    parameterField:Parameter;
    constructor(){
        initialize(parameterField)
    }

    initialize(param:never){
        this.execute();
    }
    initialize(param:object){
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Now, at this moment of my search I'm desperate and I would be fine with any ugly (but reliable) trick like the following one(but uninitialized field is undefined in both cases, and I don't have any idea if there's any other potential difference in generated code based on provided generic type):

```
class Request<Parameter,Response>{
    parameterField:Parameter;
    constructor(){
        if(typeof parameterField==="undefined"){
            //some optimization removed 'paremeterField' from object completely
            this.execute();
        }else if(typeof parameterField==="null"){
            // surely, we know that browsers optimize objects as
            // 'class instances', so providing default field with null 
            // while generating code would be beneficial? 
            //oh no, bad luck, it's not true 

            //wait here, the field was added to the object but not set to anything meaningful yet
        }else{
            //this should never happen.
        }

    }
}
```

So, at this moment I think that this problem is not solvable at all. There's no any subtle trace of type data in generated code. Typescript, it seems, only provides type checking, and in cases like that we are forced to use redundancy to both specify that the type is never and then set some flag in superclass like `isTypedNever=true` for runtime checks.

However I'm relatively new in typescript, so maybe I overlooked something, so I'm asking the question provided in the title in hope that some wise and experienced typescript guru will provide a better solution or deny its existence.

Comment: As you note, TS doesn't emit different JS based on the types of expressions, so it's a non-starter.  You can possibly flip the question around though: given JS that works at runtime, what types would you like TS to infer from them?

Comment: For example, a [factory](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCBHArtALgOXAgEkoBBAGwCcIQATATwFUoJakBvAKE6SQDNMweDgCWAe2CoM2KDgA8AISQQAHjgjBaUJACMxY8jWAA+ABTAIrKAAUQlQuspQAXEgUBKDj15J4E2VJYuEgAvL7kIFDactYANKjGXD4+fsCylJjCYpSmnuxIAL7eyaoQ8JjquRyFxYUA3LWpAXhitvZgaEEBYfARUUhyKMbKahpagTLyFgBuEJTxQ17JvE04GVk5ebXJUJgwc7kNyz44ABYiUAB0peWV7kfLRckFD7zUOJiUkuaWWm0Oc20AH4JsFXC1-h1pLhPJFtm4RupNNo1tgkCCcPR9mI+KCAq5MdjcRC7OBOpMHkVvL1ItpybgAOoiM6QqAxBbDVRI8b02SmVEQdzshLVKkrPp06GyJlnMQVVmDTmjZF4nCmPggcgsIWLfJFApAA)

Comment: Or [this one](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCBHArtALgOXAgEkoBBAGwCcIQATATwFUoJakBvAKCSQDNNg8HAEsA9sFQZsUHAB4AQkggAPHBGC0oSAEajR5GsAB8ACmARWUAAohKhNZSgAuJPICUHTtx5Ic9GMhoWLiyVgA0qEZIALyePj4qEPCYaiZuLgBuosK0ANzePAC+XvHw4jKSwTIu5gDuSGkxUUHSciDA9BHt9FGx8OQgUFqhEShGXPE8ZcAylJhCopSNE5M8wrwNAITmljZ2kA5QHiurPDgAFsJQAHSJyalu+adIxauvk3cpEMsvBS-5f2oOEwlAkLVwSEGfx4ihUag0Whwc2QAH4kHUkCNIo1os0pCFwpEkDUIPVZGMcXiqnJzBkIJRRkZvMVvP1BlpwTIAOrCC57cBQLFjJSqdSaSqtExI7BuIVRdi-VkDIYS3A8i6iFL8sCC4VwsUc-EyEy8EDkFiy4UK4qFIA).  Let me know if you want one of those as an answer

Comment: @jcalz, my strongest objection is to having to specify the same thing twice. Your example seems to solve this issue, so as an answer this idea would definitely deserve an upvote. However at the moment practical implications of choosing one of your two variants are not clear to me, and probably such nesting would look bad for real life big class. I'm also slightly worried about theoretical instanceof checks on these constructed classes.

Comment: Could you possibly flesh out the class implementation a little more so that the `Parameter` and `Response` generic types are actually used in some way?  There might be other potential solutions having a single class but I don't want to suggest something that turns out to be untenable because I'm not anticipating the category of use case properly.

Comment: Like, maybe [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCBHArtALgOXAgEkoBBAGwCcIQATATwFUoJakBvAKCR+6XnIgoUVBmxQcAHgAKSCAA8cEYLREBtALpIAPkjUhg9DQBpUAPg58e8APbAJlTPBw3KACgB0X4BFZRpIJSESpRQAFxIAKKKQc6S7HoA0kgAlsBIANYQ9DYAZkjSGhE4jsgAvqYG9JpmAJSWPI2p+W4AhD5+AUGQIVD1XE1NOAAWKVAeChDwmEputQDcVo1lSytNk9Oz-at8K3wCQiJoWLgA6ikjXeBQMqYoFgpKKkdiuJJqhXcWA4229iVOFzubaDJBQTAwCDuAEQWo7Hh7ayCYSiE4Sc4jGwzK5gG73OSKZSqVHiKSaL4NX52ByA1xzSlNcGQ4GLJprJB7MpAA)?

Comment: @jcalz base class: https://pastebin.com/Y9rFUWqV; usage 1: https://pastebin.com/2iJuthEJ; usage 2: https://pastebin.com/rr5bqzAb; probably it's not very helpful since it contains lot of unrelated things.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for a slightly expanded [mcve].  If I get a chance I'll write up my answers and you can decide if any of them are useful to you.  The main point is that TS is really just supposed to describe the behavior of JS, not add behavior to it (`enum` and `namespace` notwithstanding; they would go back in time and remove those if they could).  If you want to see generics with runtime effects we'd need to somehow get that to happen in plain JS.

Comment: @jcalz well, at the moment I believe that it became more theoretical question than practical, so I'll accept the answer containing the summary of your comments if you wish. It will also be great if you add some quote/link to prove typescript's 'describe, not add behavior' intention, and maybe couple of words about benefits or drawbacks of each example.